# parent of parent of a .. of a file/folder in python

Tags: python

is there a shorter way to find the path of the parent of the parent of the parent of a folder/file.

I am using :

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You coud define a function for this

```
get_parent(path, n):
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    for i in range(n):
        path = os.path.dirname(path)
    return path
```

Then just invoke that function

```
get_parent(path, 3)
```

It's much cleaner I think.

Answer (score 1):

This should resolve the problem:

```
print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only slightly shorter (if at all).

```
print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean 'shorter' as in literally less characters, then you can import diffrerently:

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath

dirname(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))))
```

If what you really want is to make it more readable and less likely to be incorrect, write a helper method like @laike9m says, or define constants to important directories from some known base path and use those around your project instead.